# Alternative to partial_updates for Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any alternative to partial_updates for Rails 4?
Because I have noticed that [it was deprecated](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html) and I really need it so that my database ONLY updates the fields that were recently modified.

This is the screencast that i'm following : http://railscasts.com/episodes/109-tracking-attribute-changes?autoplay=true

Comment: maybe http://vitobotta.com/workaround-activerecord-partial-updates-serialised-columns/ would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screencast you're watching was created in 2008 and is out of date. The default behavior for quite a while has been to only update modified fields - all 4.1 did was remove the (ignored) ability to configure it. Stop setting or using the `partial_updates*` methods, and everything will be fine.